# Searching/filtering a Datatable in [React]

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, api

working a tutorial and cannot access the data value stores in {data}

when i console.log(columns) it comes back undefined
following devmentorlive tutorial on React tables

```
export default function dataTable({ data }) {
    const columns = data[0] && Object.keys(data[0]);
    return (
        <table cellPadding={0} cellSpacing={0}>
            <thead>
                <tr>{data[0] && columns.map((heading) => <th>{heading}</th>)}</tr>
            </thead>
```

Comment: Could you do a  `console.log(data)` ?

Comment: comes back undefined

Comment: Please post the relevant code here .It seems either you didn't get any `data` or you didnt pass any as props .